# How to return a list of anonymous object in Linq to Sql on joining two tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, anonymous-types

I have one requirement in which I have to perform a join on two tables and return a list of the returned rows using Linq to Sql.

```
public List<T> GetProductList()
{
    var popupList = (from p in this.Products
                     join c in this.Categories 
                     on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                     select new
                     {
                         ProductID = p.ProductID,
                         ProductName= p. ProductName,
                         CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                         CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                         DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                         IsActive = p.IsActive
                     }).OrderBy(p => p.CategoryName);

    return popupList;
}
```

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: Replace `T` with `dynamic`

Comment: But why would you want it anonymous? Why not just go ahead and create a POCO?

Comment: and add a ToList() at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare a class, like below -:

```
public class ProductCategoryView
{
    public int ProductID        { get; set; }
    public strig ProductName    { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID       { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName  { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive        { get; set; }
}
```

which will have as properties the values you want to have each row of your join.

**note** I may be wrong of the types I choosed for some of your properties. So you have to correct them correspondingly.

Then you have to refactor your query:

```
public List<ProductCategoryView> GetProductList()
{
    var popupList = (from p in this.Products
                     join c in this.Categories 
                     on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                     select new JoinView
                     {
                         ProductID = p.ProductID,
                         ProductName= p. ProductName,
                         CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                         CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                         DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                         IsActive = p.IsActive
                     }).OrderBy(p => p.CategoryName)
                       .ToList();
    return popupList;
}
```

Comment: I Thought it earlier but I am concerned if it will lead to creation of a new POCO entity each time I have a requirement like this. Isn't there a generic way to return a list of anonymous entities without creating a new entity type?

Comment: This is a good practice, since you will have as views aw you need. I mean it is a clear design decision, at least for me :). If you don't like this, you use the dynamic. I could reedit my my post later, if it is not clear.

Comment: Hi @Christos, the answer you proposed is clear enough. However I have also found a way of doing this using IQueryable return type. Could you suggest me the advantages and disadvantages of using IQueryable as return type for anonymous types.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found a way of doing this using `IQueryable` return type. Could you suggest me the advantages and disadvantages of using `IQueryable` as return type for anonymous types.

```
public IQueryable GetProductList()
{
    var popupList = from p in this.Products
                     join c in this.Categories 
                     on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                     select new
                     {
                         ProductID = p.ProductID,
                         ProductName= p. ProductName,
                         CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                         CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                         DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                         IsActive = p.IsActive
                     };
    return popupList.OrderBy(p => p.CategoryName);
}
```

Comment: Don't think it will compile since `List<T>` doesn't implement `IQueryable` (unless you want to call `AsQueryable()` at the return statement). In any case, why `IQueryable` over `IEnumerable` ? To answer your question, you lose type information. Since you return an anonymous object, you can't actually cast the objects returned. Only thing left is `dynamic` type and you might as well return a list of `dynamic`. All in all, creating a POCO is the safer and clear route for all consumers of the method.

Comment: You are right @SimonBelanger, actually I had not used OrderBy and ToList in my code, I have also removed it from my post.